# Suppose that F is a non-empty family of sets, B is a set, and $\forall A\in F (A\subseteq B).$ Prove that $\cup F\subseteq B$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose $x\in \cup F$, then $\forall A \in F (x\in A)$. Since $\forall A \in F (A\subseteq B)$ , $x\in B$.

Is this correct? Its obvious that for any element $x \in \cup F$ , x will be in some $A\in F$, which in turn, $x\in B$ since any $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: By $\cup F$ do you mean $\cup_{A\in F}A$ ? Then it seems correct.

Comment: Sorry about my oversight, the other person is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Contradicting what has been said in the comments, your answer is not (totally) correct.

Just like the OP mentioned in the comments, he defines $\cup F = \cup_{A \in F} A.$ Therefore, when you suppose $x \in \cup F$, one can't guaratee that $x \in A,$ for every set $A \in F$ (this is something the OP stated to be true). What we can do is the following:

Since $x \in \cup F,$ by definition of union of sets we can guarantee that **there exists at least one set** $A \in F$ such that $x \in A$ (note that this is not necessarily true for every set $A \in F$).

The rest of the resolution is correct and remains the same after this correction.

Comment: if we suppose $x\in \cup F$, this means x is an arbitrary element of $\cup F$ , right? Then $\exists x \in \cup F (x\in A)$. Since $\forall A \in F (A\subseteq B)$ it follows that $x \in B$

Comment: "if we suppose $x \in \cup F,$ this means $x$ is an arbitrary element of $\cup F$" is a correct statement. "Then $\exists x \in \cup F (x \in A)$": this makes no sense. What is $A$? .When you assume that $x$ is an arbitrary element of $\cup F = \cup_{A \in F} A$, the only thing you can guarantee is that $\exists A \in F$ such that $x \in A.$ Note that $A$ does not need to be unique but certainly not every set in $F$ has to verify this.

Comment: You’re right, I missed that mistake. It’s that OP wrote out the logic correctly in the second paragraph. Which suggests that maybe they are getting lost in the notation.

Comment: @xyz This is what i understand $\cup F=\cup_{i=I} A_{i}=\left \{ x|\forall i \in I(x\in A_{i}) \right \}$. So instead of $\exists x \in \cup F (x\in A)$, then it would be better to say $\forall i \in I(x\in A_{i})$ and then $\forall A_{i} \in F(A_{i}\subseteq B)$

Comment: What you wrote is not correct. First, $\cup F = \cup_{i = I} A_i = A_I,$ which doesn't make sense (what is $I$?). A correct definition of this would be: $$ \cup F = \cup_{A \in F} A = \{ x \, | \, x \in A, \text{ for at least one set } A \in F\}.$$  I believe your main problem is in understanding what is the definition on union of sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))